# Vectorising Nested For Loops

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I wrote this code and it works fine but I would like to optimize it by removing the two for loops if possible. Does anybody have any ideas how I might achieve this? Many thanks!

```
chosen_runs = [2:5];

% Configurations for each test in order
XY = [0 1; 0 1; 0 9; 0 1; 0 2; 0 3; 0 4; 0 5; 11 12; 11 12];

% Inductance Matrix
LMat = [0.0045  0.0045  0.0045  0.0044  0.0044  0.0044  0.0044  0.0044  0.0043  0.0043;
        0.0045  0.0046  0.0046  0.0045  0.0045  0.0045  0.0045  0.0044  0.0044  0.0044;
        0.0045  0.0046  0.0046  0.0046  0.0046  0.0046  0.0045  0.0045  0.0045  0.0045;
        0.0044  0.0045  0.0046  0.0047  0.0047  0.0047  0.0046  0.0046  0.0046  0.0046;
        0.0044  0.0045  0.0046  0.0047  0.0048  0.0048  0.0047  0.0047  0.0047  0.0046;
        0.0044  0.0045  0.0046  0.0047  0.0048  0.0048  0.0048  0.0048  0.0048  0.0047;
        0.0044  0.0045  0.0045  0.0046  0.0047  0.0048  0.0049  0.0049  0.0049  0.0048;
        0.0044  0.0044  0.0045  0.0046  0.0047  0.0048  0.0049  0.0050  0.0049  0.0049;
        0.0043  0.0044  0.0045  0.0046  0.0047  0.0048  0.0049  0.0049  0.0050  0.0050;
        0.0043  0.0044  0.0045  0.0046  0.0046  0.0047  0.0048  0.0049  0.0050  0.0051];

% Declaration of Variables
runs = chosen_runs;
num = length(runs);
in_point = zeros(num,1);
out_point = zeros(num,1);
L_Mid = zeros(10,num);
L_Sides = zeros(10,num);

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

in_point = XY(runs,1);    % Creates a column vector each row of which is the in_point for a chosen run
out_point = XY(runs,2);   % Creates a column vector each row of which is the out_point for a chosen run

in_point
out_point

for k = 1:10
    for l = 1:num

        L_Mid(k,l) = sum(LMat(k,1+in_point(l):out_point(l)));     % Creates a matrix, each column of which is the inductance (in between current leads) for a chosen run, each row is a different layer in the solenoid.
        L_Sides(k,l) = sum(LMat(k,:))-L_Mid(k,l);    % Creates a matrix, each column of which is the inductance (either side of the current leads) for a chosen run, each row is a different layer in the solenoid.

    end
end

L_Mid
L_Sides
```

Comment: Can you minimize this to an even [shorter example](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to vectorise this code:

```
for k = 1:10
    for l = 1:num
        L_Mid(k,l) = sum(LMat(k,1+in_point(l):out_point(l)));  
        L_Sides(k,l) = sum(LMat(k,:))-L_Mid(k,l); 
    end
end
```

First step, removing the outer loop:

```
for l=1:num
    L_Mid(:,l)=sum(LMat(:,1+in_point(l):out_point(l)),2); % Using the dim input to sum
    L_Sides(:,l) = bsxfun(@minus,sum(LMat,2),L_Mid(:,l)); % Using bsxfun to subtract
end
```

Next step, L_Sides can be created with a single operation:

```
for l=1:num
    L_Mid(:,l)=sum(LMat(:,1+in_point(l):out_point(l)),2); % Using the dim input to sum
end

L_Sides = bsxfun(@minus,sum(LMat,2),L_Mid);
```

Since the length of in_point(l):out_point(l) is variable, there is no tidy way to vectorize this (that I know of; anyone got a good way I'd love to know!), and you can just leave it as is, or use this:

```
L_Mid2 = arrayfun(@(x) ...
    sum(LMat(:,1+in_point(x):out_point(x)),2), 1:length(in_point),'uniformoutput',false);
L_Mid2=cat(2,L_Mid2{:})
```

But there will be no performance benefit and it is less obvious what is going on, so I would not use this code.

Comment: That's very elegant Hugh! I am impressed! Thank you